# Include image in tikz with pixel unit

Tags: tikz-pgf

In tikzpicture, I can set 1pt as unit but 1px doesn't work! So I guess 1pt equal to 1px. But sounds like almost but not exactly!

This is a example. Original image is 200x150 but the node display is 200.74948ptx150.5621pt!

Should it be exactly 200x150? What's correct way to get 200x150?

```
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[x=1pt,y=1pt]
    %image source: /usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist//latex/mwe/example-image-4x3.png
    \node[anchor=south west,inner sep=0,outer sep=0] (image) at (0,0)       
        {\includegraphics{example-image-4x3}};
    \draw[line width=0.1pt] let 
        \p1=(image.south west),
        \p2=(image.north east),
        \n1={(\x2-\x1)},
        \n2={(\y2-\y1)}  
        in node[anchor=west] at (0,120) {\large \n1,\n2};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can not tell you *why* this happens, but I stumbled over this some time ago, and at least back then I did not know if there is a deeper reason. If you look up the conversion rate in the web, you will find that

```
1cm = 28.3465pt   (in web).
```

However, Ti*k*Z claims, as shown in the MWE below, it is

```
1cm = 28.45274pt  (Ti*k*Z).
```

If you factor in that slight discrepancy, you get, within the rounding errors, a perfect match, as the lowest line in the following output reveals.

```
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[x=1pt,y=1pt]
    %image source: /usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist//latex/mwe/example-image-4x3.png
    \node[anchor=south west,inner sep=0,outer sep=0] (image) at (0,0)       
        {\includegraphics{example-image-4x3}};
    \draw[line width=0.1pt] let 
        \p1=(image.south west),
        \p2=(image.north east),
        \n1={(\x2-\x1)},
        \n2={(\y2-\y1)}  
        in node[anchor=west] at (0,120) {\large \n1,\n2};
    \path let \p1=(1cm,0) in node[anchor=west,fill=white] at (0,90) {$\x1\ne 28.3465pt$};   
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\myconv}{28.3465pt/28.45274}
    \draw[line width=0.1pt] let 
        \p1=(image.south west),
        \p2=(image.north east),
        \n1={(\x2-\x1)*\myconv},
        \n2={(\y2-\y1)*\myconv}  
        in node[anchor=west] at (0,40) {\large \n1,\n2};    
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, what's more, if I add [width=200pt] to includepicture, then I can get 200pt width, but the height is 150.01074pt.

Comment: @beetlej I am not really sure, but to me this sounds like a rounding error.